How can i bridge eth interfaces with no bridge (let me explain)
I have a device that has 3 ETH interfaces.
This way I installed the Ubuntu server on it to use the Pi-Hole application
I want to use my ETH0 to receive the Wan cable from my internet provider moden and use ETH1 and ETH2 to connect a computer and a Wifi Access Point
I've already tried to use Brige through Netplan but Pi-hole doesn't work and as it is a DHCP server and I also can't access management through the network by Putty
How can I proceed to have the wan internet input on port 0 so that it is processed by the pi-hole and later accessed through ports 1 and 2?
